# Is it a good idea to protect a exe file using os.path.exists?

Tags: python, file, exe

Is it a good idea to use:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists (file_path)
```

to "protect" a program against copies?

For example, in our main application, we use:

```
import os.path
os.path.exists ("c:\windows\mifile.dll")
```

where `mifile.dll` is anything, of course with another name like `windriv.dll` and just a simple text saved with Notepad.

If the file exists the program works, if not then it displays a warning message that it's a illegal copy or something.

When installing the program, I do the normal installation of the package or the portable folder and manually copy the file `mifile.dll` in `c:\windows`.

Comment: Errr - 1) how on earth would this protect against copies, and 2) not sure I'd like programs that feel the need to copy into the root of the windows directory

Comment: 1) For low level users it will work I think..... 2) OK, maybe Program Files or something like this?

Comment: And how on earth are you preventing your users from just reading the Python sources/disassemble your Python module?!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't the best idea.

1. A lot of people (such as myself and possibly virus programs) watch the windows directory and would delete something like this.
2. This kind of thing might be better to be encrypted
3. Catching an import error isn't the easiest thing
4. If you are worried about illegal copies it wouldn't be long until somebody figured this out and you have a file that can be copied easily and distributed easily.
5. Using an import and erroring out would be a huge red flag to a reverse engineer
6. With UAC this file might not be accessible without running the program as an administrator

Comment: 1, 2, 3, 5 and 6 OK.
4 Yes I am worried about illegal copies but It's not a national treasure, I only need some protection, I mean, avoid the copy and past and the software is running on every computer. Do you have some clue to protect the software?

Comment: First level procedures would be put some values in the registry that are checked.  The simplest would a just to encrypt a string with a key embedded in the code.  Something like "MyAwesomeSoftware" + MachineName (or some other computer identifier)

Answer (score 1):

No.

Whichever solution you end up with, the general idea of a "secret handshake install technique" is basically **sabotage**.  You are effectively preventing your customers from:

- Upgrading the OS of the machine
- Restoring their system from a backup
- Moving your service to a new machine because of hardware failure

The customer *will* need to do either of these within the next few years.  When they do, your program will break, and they will not know why or how to fix it.  Given that you are even available to them at this time, think of how this makes you look when they contact you to fix the issue.

If *I* found out that a subcontractor had secretly introduced themselves as a single point of failure like this, I would be bloody furious.

*Either trust your customers, get new customers that you can trust, or go for a fully professional non-secret DRM solution.*

Comment: Thanks Deestan, new point of view for me.

"Either trust your customers, get new customers that you can trust" the problem are not my customers, but the external hardware technicians, they can see the program and take a copy and then make money :)

Comment: Yes, but remember that as long as you specifically sell X instance licenses to a specific customer, copying them around is illegal and you can sue for damages.  Technicians re-selling your software is downright piracy and you can sue them even harder.  Good luck. :-)